# How to use "to"

Tags: to-infinitive

I am brazilian and I have some questions. So, What is the correct use to this sentences..."I need to back to home or I need back to home or I need to back home"? 
thank you

Comment: None of them. You are probably missing a verb that will be part of the *to-infinitive*, as in 'I need *to go/to get* back home'. But I don't know what you're trying to say, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Well, it was during a conversation practise between two students. So, I have no sure about how to correct it...

Comment: One more question, please. "Do you want to buy the dress tomorrow for you mom? or Do you want to buy the dress tomorrow to your mom - What is the correct sentence?

Comment: You  buy something *for* somebody, so the first sentence!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "to" does not go by itself.  It goes with a verb.  When "to" and a verb are together, it is called an *infinitive*.  You must have the verb for the sentence to make sense:

> I need to go back home.

or

> I need to go back to my home.

Comment: But, back could be the sentence verb?

Comment: @Teachermanoeltavares: No.  "back" is not a verb in this context.  It is an adverb that modifies the verb "go".  You don't just "go home".  "back" gives more information about going home, but it is not a verb in itself.

Comment: Ok. I understood. Very clear now. Tks.